# Codeigniter PHP Message: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I got this error when I update the status of order from 1 to 2.

> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Here's my Model:

```
public function confirm_order($status, $cart_id)
{
    $this->db->where('cart_id',$cart_id);
    $this->db->update('cart',$status);
    return $query->result();
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function confirm_order($cart_id)
{   
    $status = array
    (
        'status'=>2
    );
    $this->queries_order->confirm_order($cart_id,$status);
    redirect('get_order_details');
}
```

Comment: which line does generate the error ?

Comment: you should print `$status` and `$cart_id` and show the result

Comment: check your parameters are swapped wrong. status, cart_id  => cart_id, status

Comment: Oh thank you sir cjmling :) , now it work

Comment: @Dave I posted it as answer. If it solve your problem please accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems OP have typo in parameter, swapping the position between two solved his problem.

`confirm_order($cart_id,$status);` should be changed to `confirm_order($status, $cart_id);`